# What do you doing?

Tags: pronunciation, listening

Recently, I've listened to a simple conversation for kids. In the tapescripts, it's **what are you doing?**, but i've heard that the boy said **what do you doing?** .Although I've adjusted the speed, I still heard it was 'do' instead of 'are'. 
Therefore, I wonder if there are any pronunciation rules making 'what are' sound like 'what do'. A friend of mine says americans usually pronounce 't' like 'd', and 'are' will be pronounced like 'ə', so that the reason why 'what are' sounds like 'what do'. Is it right? Could you make it clearer? Thank you!
Here is the tape. From 3:45.
 https://youtu.be/lVHnBjEwePs

Comment: Link to tape please... You are definitely mishearing stuff.

Comment: I think so. I've just added. I need your help. :(

Comment: This phrase is used so often that we often pronounce it very indistinctly. It could sound like "What'r ya doing?" or even "Whaddaya doing?". Nonetheless if we pronounce it carefully, we'll always say "What are you doing?" rather than "What do you doing?"

Comment: In intervocalic position, American "t" is mostly pronounced as something close to a "d".  For example, "ladder" and "latter" are pronounced identically by most AmE speakers, and the consonant used generally sounds like a /d/.  "What are", if pronounced in fluent speech, has an intervocalic "t", hence the "wadda" noted by The Photon above.